# Java AWT Draw on Translucent Frame

Tags: java, awt

I am having trouble drawing on a translucent frame.  When the "alphaValue" is 255 everything works as expected.  But I need a translucent frame.  I created a small test class below that demonstrates the problem.  As you can see the "MIDDLE" rectangle appears all the time.  But the "DRAW" rectangle only appears when "alphaValue" is 255.  When it is <=254 you can see via print lines that the method is still called, but the image does not appear to refresh.  Thank you in advance for any help.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Panel;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class TransparencyTest {
    private static Point startPoint = new Point();
    private static Point endPoint = new Point();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TransparencyTest().test();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    private void test() {
        int alphaValue = 255;

        Frame myFrame = new Frame();
        myFrame.setUndecorated(true);
        myFrame.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, alphaValue));
        myFrame.setSize(800, 800);

        Panel myPanel = new Panel() {
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                super.paint(g);
                System.out.println("PAINT");
                g.setColor(new Color(255, 0, 0, 255));
                if(startPoint.equals(new Point())) {
                    System.out.println("MIDDLE");
                    g.drawRect(200, 200, 400, 400);
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("DRAW");
                    g.drawRect(
                            (int)Math.min(startPoint.getX(), endPoint.getX()),
                            (int)Math.min(startPoint.getY(), endPoint.getY()),
                            (int)Math.abs(startPoint.getX() - endPoint.getX()),
                            (int)Math.abs(startPoint.getY() - endPoint.getY())
                    );
                }
            }
        };
        myFrame.add(myPanel);

        MouseAdapter myMouseAdapter = new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                startPoint = e.getPoint();
            }

            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                endPoint = e.getPoint();
                myPanel.repaint();
            }
        };
        myPanel.addMouseListener(myMouseAdapter);
        myPanel.addMouseMotionListener(myMouseAdapter);

        myFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're also mixing heavy weight and light weight components, may consider using JPanel over panel. It may not fix this problem, but it will prevent other possible issues

Comment: I don't believe Panel has a paintComponent method.  With an alpha value of 254, I would think that I would still see a drawn rectangle instead of nothing.

Comment: Using a heavy weight component, like `Panel` could be "part" of the problem.  I'd question why you're using AWT components directly

Comment: Works fine for me (alpha set to 128), was able to see both `PAINT` and `DRAW` when I dragged the mouse about

Comment: I just switch to JFrame and JPanel.  I implemented paintComponent.  How do I make the rectangle opaque (alpha 255).  if the Frame is setOpacity(.1).

Comment: Okay, seem to getting my methods mixed up, opacity affects ALL the components, setBackground effects the frame only - my bad.  I've dropped the alpha value down to 1 and it still works (with setBackground)

Comment: When I set the background of the frame with alpha 10.  It is still fully opaque.  The only way I was able to get it translucent was with setOpacity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94367/discussion-between-joe-and-madprogrammer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWT components don't have a concept of transparency in of themselves, they are always opaque.

You have use a `JPanel`, which you use `setOpaque` to control the opacity (on or off) with.  This will allow the panel to become see through and you should then be able to see the alpha affect applied directly to the frame...

[image: Transparent]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TransparencyTest {

    private static Point startPoint = new Point();
    private static Point endPoint = new Point();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                new TransparencyTest().test();
            }
        });
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    private void test() {
        int alphaValue = 128;

        JFrame myFrame = new JFrame();
        myFrame.setUndecorated(true);
        myFrame.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, alphaValue));
//      myFrame.setOpacity(0.1f);
        myFrame.setSize(800, 800);
        myFrame.setLocation(100, 100);

        JPanel myPanel = new JPanel() {
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);

                System.out.println("PAINT");
                g.setColor(new Color(255, 0, 0, 255));
                if (startPoint.equals(new Point())) {
                    System.out.println("MIDDLE");
                    g.drawRect(200, 200, 400, 400);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("DRAW");
                    g.drawRect(
                            (int) Math.min(startPoint.getX(), endPoint.getX()),
                            (int) Math.min(startPoint.getY(), endPoint.getY()),
                            (int) Math.abs(startPoint.getX() - endPoint.getX()),
                            (int) Math.abs(startPoint.getY() - endPoint.getY())
                    );
                }
            }
        };
        myPanel.setOpaque(false);
        myFrame.add(myPanel);

        MouseAdapter myMouseAdapter = new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                startPoint = e.getPoint();
            }

            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                endPoint = e.getPoint();
                myPanel.repaint();
            }
        };
        myPanel.addMouseListener(myMouseAdapter);
        myPanel.addMouseMotionListener(myMouseAdapter);

        myFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: You sir are a wizard, and I wish I could give you more than one up vote.